# Get Generic Container Type

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to find out if a `Type` I'm working with is a Generic 'container', for example if I have a `List<int>` I need to check if I'm working with a List (I know how to get whether I'm working with an `int`), how would I do that? (I'm thinking Reflection). Another example, I have a class called `StructContainer<T>`, I need to find the word (name) 'StructContainer', I'm not too bothered with what 'T' is, using reflection I get `StructContainer'1`, would hate to have to do some string splitting etc  /EDIT: Just to explain further, `StructContainer<int>` I need 'StructContainer', `Tuple<int>` I need 'Tuple', `List<int>` I need 'List' and so forth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string type = yourObject.GetType().Name.Split('`')[0];
```

Comment: I hope I will not have to do this, but it is starting to look like my only option...

Answer (score 4):

Your first question can be achieved in multiple ways:

1. Check whether your object implements `IEnumerable<T>`: `yourObject is IEnumerable<int>`. This only works if you know the type of the object in the container (`int` in this case)
2. Use the same solution I described below, just change `StructContainer` to `List`.

As to your second question, you can do this:

```
var yourObject = new StructContainer<int>();
var yourType = yourObject.GetType();
if(yourType.IsGenericType &&
   yourType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(StructContainer<>))
    // ...
```

Comment: That tells me whether it is what I suspect it could be. Maybe my first question confused the matter, I need to get the name of the containing type, without having any clue what it could be, similar to Type.Name

Comment: @Adriaan: When you have a `List<int>` object, you want to get `int` as a result?

Comment: Nope, `List<int>` must give `List`, `StructContainer<int>` must give 'StructContainer`

Comment: My answer helps you with exactly that.

Comment: Your answer helps with checking if it is a List or a StructContainer, what if I had a Tuple<T>, then I need to get `Tuple`

Comment: Ah, you want the name as a string?

Comment: The name of the containing type is not `StructContainer`. This would be a type without any generic parameters. The name of your type if StructContainer`1. Because of this, there is no way to get what you want but to use string operations.